# CSS won't flip a unicode font icon and won't change it's color on hover

Tags: css

I have 2 problems:

1. The unicode icon twitter won't flip
2. All unicode icons won't change color on hover (Only the background)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/der7zb9k/4/):

**HTML**

```
<span class="icon-twitter-circle"></span> Follow us</br>
<span class="icon-facebook-circle"></span> Like us
```

**CSS**

```
[class^=icon] {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, Verdana, "Courier New", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
    /* UNICODE only! No custom font files. No images */
}
[class^=icon-facebook]:before {
    content: "\024D5";
    content: "\00066";
    color: #0000FF;

    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
[class^=icon-twitter]:before {
    content: "\01F426";
    color: #3366FF;
    font-size: 1em;

    transform: scale(-1, 1); /* Flips the text */
}
[class$=-circle] {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 0.30em; /* Size of circle */
    margin: 0.10em 0.0em; /* Line spacing */
    border: 1px solid #000;

    line-height: 20px; /* Centers the character Horizontally, on it's Y-axis */
    text-align: center; /* Centers the character vertically, on it's X-axis */
}
[class^=icon-twitter]:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
[class^=icon-facebook]:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

### Note

I just leaned and would like to point out that **`transform` WON'T work unless the element is displayed `display: block` or `display: inline-block`**. Hence, `icon-twitter` won't flip unless I add `.icon-twitter {display: inline-block; ... transform...`

Comment: yeah the answer below is right `[class^=icon-twitter]:hover:before {` is the selector you want but these characters won't take colors as they are multicolor on some systems (mac)

Comment: I want to point out that **`transform` WON'T work unless the element is displayed `display: block` or `display: inline-block`**. Hence, `icon-twitter` won't flip unless I add `.icon-twitter {display: inline-block`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your hover color doesnt work because you set the color on the `:before` pseudo-element, but you are trying to change the color on hover of the actual element. They are 2 different things.

target `:hover:before` instead.

[Fixed here.](http://jsfiddle.net/der7zb9k/6/)

Changed code is:

```
[class^=icon-twitter]:hover,
[class^=icon-twitter]:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #3366FF;
}
[class^=icon-facebook]:hover,
[class^=icon-facebook]:hover:before {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #0000FF;
}
```

Comment: I'll use `[class^=icon-facebook] { color:... }` rather than `[class^=icon-facebook]:hover:before`

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the color and flip to the main element, not the before element, OR you need to target the `:hover:before` instead of just `:hover`

[Fixed code using first method.](https://jsfiddle.net/3gg8g4an/)

Comment: I'll use `[class^=icon-facebook] { color:... }` rather than `[class^=icon-facebook]:hover:before`

Comment: Apologies, thought I had. Updated the link in the comment with the correct code.